# Como puedo extraer subcadenas de una cadena en C++_

Tags: c++, string, archivo, txt, substr

Necesito extraer al menos 3 subcadenas de un archivo de text (.txt) y solo logro obtener 2.
El archivo de texto unicamente consta de una linea y solo posee lo siguiente:

admin,MEROMERO,12345

Aun no se como hacer para que el proceso puedo repetirse mas veces para extraer mas subcadenas de la misma linea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string nombre, apo, contra, linea, datos[3];
size_t pos;

int contador;

int main(){
    
    fstream archivo ("datos.txt");
    
    while(getline(archivo, linea)){
        while((pos = linea.find(","))!= string::npos){
            datos[contador] = linea.substr(0, pos);
            
            linea.erase(0, pos+1);
            
            contador++;     
            
        }   
    }
    
    nombre = datos[0];
    apo = datos[1];
    contra = datos[2];
    
    cout << nombre << endl;
    cout << apo << endl;
    cout << contra << endl;
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Luego de que ya llegaste a la ultima `,` el ciclo terminara y quedara una sola palabra. Luego del `while` solo haz algo tipo `datos[contador] = linea` y deberia estar. Notese que `contador` no esta inicializado, puede que tu programa en el IDE en modo debug lo inicialize a `0`, pero en un entorno real eso no esta garantizado, te recomiendo que lo inicialices explicitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo que quieres con [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Solo tienes que establecer el tercer parámetro en `','`.

Así:

```
string datos[3];
int contador = 0;

while(getline(cin, datos[contador], ',')){
    contador++;
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##TY3NDoIwEITvfYqNHoC0JibcpJKoj6EcmlJxE1gILfFgeHZs@Ynu5dvMzs7orjtUWk/THknXQ2lAYmtdb1STs5/mFaQqZ2ywnkCqMbZT2oB1ZcYYkoNGIcXJh4GfxQ6lcq29p0U2i8GkW3KqbHs4w3FR3y@sTVwZVyOZWCOJ9W2zFgIiESVrcpjtwvkSMbIZTx8bhxKc0z0kpB6cJ3@vgwMpw03C7gS7wKUPi7BHD4oyNk7TRcBVwO0L).